# Botnet fingerprinting

Tags: botnet, research, fingerprinting

Does anyone know of any research of papers on fingerprinting botnets?  If a given target is being brute forced or DDoSed do methods exist to determine if a brute force or DDoS on another target are coming from the same botnet?  Based on geography of the nodes and time of day given nodes are attacking?  I'm talking prolonged attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to post a page of links, but you will find a ton of research at this link:

http://www.cyberwarzone.com/understanding-and-mitigating-ddos-attacks-tools